# Customizing GMapControl exception tiles

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

I am using a GMapControl in  C# programming. I am selecting the map type from a combobox. After selection, the respective map appears. If in case the map is not available or internet is not working, it loads the map with exception tiles. I would like to customize the exception tiles in my map control.
The map names are taken from the GMapProviders.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = GMapProviders.List.ToArray();

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MainMap.MapProvider = (GMapProvider)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    }
    catch { MessageBox.Show("Sorry No map Available"); }
}
```

How do I customize the exception tiles? It is never entering the exception part.

Comment: Are you talking about MessageBox.Show method? It has lot of options - title, icon, buttons. Just look [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show)

Comment: No, I am not bothered about the message box. I would like to customize the exception tiles which appear on the screen. The combo box is loaded by predefined map types so, it does not go to exception.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `WinForms` based on the code above. To make it short, your options are limited in the current state.

Pretend you have no cached tiles and no internet connection available, then the (empty) tile is drawn from gmap.net.

You can somewhat change the look by editing the map's `Empty[...]` properties (background, text etc.) like so:

```
MainMap.EmptyTileText = "Sorry, no data available.";
MainMap.EmptyTileColor = Color.Beige;
MainMap.EmptyMapBackground = Color.BlanchedAlmond;
```

But you will not get rid of the exception, that is being baked into the tile (at least I've found no easy way), referencing [this code](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/master/GMap.NET.Core/GMap.NET/GMaps.cs#L706).

Comment: That said nothing keeps you from editing the source and creating a pull request, if you really want to get involved.

Comment: Is there any way out to display a blank screen if there is no internet connection available instead of cached tiles?

Comment: Not built-in, I believe. You could turn visibility off if you find out that the internet connection is not available, e.g. by querying a tile outside of gmap.net.

Comment: Please let me know how to query a tile outside the gmap.net

Comment: In general every tile you request is done through an HTTP request to an URL of the map provider. You can check one URL for a minimal request, if that one fails, it's likely that the service is not available or the internet connection is not available. In that case just set the visibility to invisible and present your custom message/dialog etc.